# Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's suppose I have an associative array like this one

```
var client1={
    "id":"1"
    "category":"Interiorism",
    "photo1":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient1.jpg",
    "photo2":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient2.jpg",
    "photo3":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient3.jpg",
    "photo4":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient4.jpg",
    };

var client2={
    .
    .
    .
    };



allClients=[client1, client2..., clientx];
```

I want to set up a function that pushs the photo keys in an empty array. The problem is that not all the clients have the same number of photos, so I am using 'for'. Here is the function I wrote

```
function photoKeys()
{
    var keyList=Object.keys(allClients[id]);
    var numKey=parseInt(listaKeys.length);

    var photoAlbum=[];  //here I want to put the photo URL's


    for (i=2; i<=numFotos; i++)
    {
        ????????????
    }

}
```

Here is the problem, how I can write the photo object from the client array whith the i var from the 'for' function?

I tried this but didn't work

```
for (i=2; i<=numFotos; i++)
        {
            photoAlbum.push(allClients[id].photo+'i');
        }
```

Comment: Honestly, if you have the option, it would probably be more reasonable to make a sub-array called "photos" that contains all the photos. That way you can just iterate through that without worrying about concatenating to some string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should be accessing the photo paths like:

```
photoAlbum.push(allClients[id]['photo' + i]);
```

But i would really recommend you to change the format of your client object to something like this:

```
var client1 = {
    "id"       :"1"
    "category" :"Interiorism",
    "photos"   : [
        "img/ClientCorp/photoClient1.jpg",
        "img/ClientCorp/photoClient2.jpg",
        ...
    ]
};
```

Or this, if you need to store those "photo1", "photo2" ids:

```
var client2 = {
    "id"       :"1"
    "category" :"Interiorism",
    "photos"   : [
        {
            "id"   : "photo1",
            "path" :"img/ClientCorp/photoClient1.jpg"
        },
        ...
    ]
};
```

Then you can iterate them way easier like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allClients[id].photos.length; i++){
    photoAlbum.push(allClients[id].photos[i]);
    //or this for the second format:
    //photoAlbum.push(allClients[id].photos[i].path);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I changed the format like you suggested me and now is all much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your current code would be parsed like this:

```
photoAlbum.push(allClients[id].photo + 'i');
```

It would try to evaluate `allClients[id].photo` and then append the string `i`. You need to access the property name using bracket notation instead of dot notation.

You also have the symbol and string part backward, `photo` is the string and `i` is your index variable.

```
photoAlbum.push(allClients[id]['photo' + i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The big thing to understand is that `client` in your example isn't an array, it's an object.

```
var client1={
    "id":"1"
    "category":"Interiorism",
    "photo1":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient1.jpg",
    "photo2":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient2.jpg",
    "photo3":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient3.jpg",
    "photo4":"img/ClientCorp/photoClient4.jpg",
};
```

You *can* acquire an object's keys as an array using `Object.keys(client1)`, or you can loop through all an object's keys using `for...in` syntax.

If you want to feed an arbitrary number (`numFotos`) of property values from your object into an array called `photoAlbum`, you can use the following syntax:

```
var i = 0;
for(var key in client1){
    photoAlbum.push(client1[key]);
    if(++i >= numFotos){
       break; // break out of the loop if i equals or exceeds numFotos
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer!